# Deleting Blob from Azure storage using C#

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

The package which I am using is `Azure.Storage.Blobs` (v12.9.1) and I am trying to delete a blob.

Here is the code I have written (I do not get any errors):

```
//path - storage url without token 
public async Task<bool> DeleteFilefromStorage(string path)
{
        try
        {
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(Helper.StorageCS);

            string containerName = Helper.ContainerName;

            Uri uri = new Uri(path);
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);

            BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

            var blob = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(filename);

            return await blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's you question?

Comment: @GauravMantri How to i delete a blob from container including the snapshots using the new Azure.Storage.Blobs(12.9.1) package.

Comment: Have you read the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.deleteifexistsasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_DeleteIfExistsAsync_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_DeleteSnapshotsOption_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)?

Comment: **Please edit your question and provide all the information there only instead of comments**. What's the value of `path` variable? Also include the issues you're running into.

Comment: specified what is path and I do not run into any issues, I don't get error also my blob doesn't get deleted.

Comment: Please check if the blob.Uri matches with your path variable.

Comment: To catch the error, please use [`DeleteAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.deleteasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_DeleteAsync_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_DeleteSnapshotsOption_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_). Most likely you're getting a 404 error which is kind of eaten by `DeleteIfExistsAsync`.

Comment: Yes, It matches

Comment: Yes using DeleteAsync, I get an error and it says that the specified blob doesn't exist while the blob.Uri and the path are the same.

Comment: Can you share the actual value? Just obfuscate the account name before sharing. Also check if the blob indeed exists in your storage account.

Comment: Blob Exists in my storage account and my actual path -  

https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/files/ba143f66-ba18-478a-85d6-0d661e6894dd.xlsx

Comment: Aah...I see what the issue is. Essentially your blob is inside a virtual folder called `files`. However when you do `Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);` you will only get `ba143f66-ba18-478a-85d6-0d661e6894dd.xlsx` instead of `files/ba143f66-ba18-478a-85d6-0d661e6894dd.xlsx`. This is why you're getting 404 error.

Comment: Yes, Finally... This works. Thank you so much. Please post the answer I will approve it so that others can use it. thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code is failing is because your blob URL is something like `https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/files/ba143f66-ba18-478a-85d6-0d661e6894dd.xlsx` where the file (`ba143f66-ba18-478a-85d6-0d661e6894dd.xlsx`) is inside a virtual folder called `files`.

However when you do `string filename = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);`, it will only return `ba143f66-ba18-478a-85d6-0d661e6894dd.xlsx` and not `files/ba143f66-ba18-478a-85d6-0d661e6894dd.xlsx`.

Because of this when you try to delete the file, you will get a 404 error. Since `DeleteIfExistsAsync` method will eat `404 (Not Found)` error, you will not get any errors but at the same time the blob will not be deleted as well (because it does not exist).